# React - history push throwing error: Failed to execute 'pushState' on 'History'

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router-dom

I have a page on the URL:`http://localhost:10001/track/8311c15a-7f7f-47ff-b81a-6f6904ad191c/my-form` where I have a form. After the form is submitted I am using react's router history to redirect to a success page

```
const MyComponent = ({match, location, history}: RouteComponentProps

const onSubmit = () => {
  history.push(`/${baseUrl}/success`)
}
```

But, when I try to do so, I get an error:

```
Uncaught DOMException: Failed to execute 'pushState' on 'History': A history state object with URL 'http://track/8311c15a-7f7f-47ff-b81a-6f6904ad191c/success' cannot be created in a document with origin 'http://localhost:10001' and URL 'http://localhost:10001/track/8311c15a-7f7f-47ff-b81a-6f6904ad191c/my-form'.
```

It is the first time I have encountered this error. What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: check the `baseUrl`, it may contain a wrong value

Answer (score 0):

as mentioned in https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/History/pushState#parameters:

> The new URL must be of the same origin as the current URL; otherwise,
> pushState() will throw an exception.

As I can understand, the error message that you have been shared says about that.